# How to delete a detached subscription in Google Cloud Pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I detached a subscription using the GUI at https://console.cloud.google.com/. The detachment went fine. Now I want to delete the subscription and need the subscription ID. I can't find it anywhere in the UI or when I run  `gcloud pubsub subscriptions list` in the built in Cloud Shell terminal.

I expected the subscription to still appear in the subscription list in the project view. I assumed I would then be able to delete it from the UI.
I also expected that the subscription would show up when I listed the subscriptions from the cloud shell terminal but it was not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a detached subscription should still appear in the list of subscriptions. A separate delete action is required to remove it.

Is it possible someone else or an automated system deleted the subscription for you?

Comment: It must have been an automated system. It's definitely gone now. Thanks for the reply!